# ¿Por qué se produce el error System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

El error se produce en el método `ListaSedes()` donde imprimo todas las que he llenado. La excepción se produce en el método que imprime los datos provenientes de los get de otra clase, pero la instancia la creé bien, entonces no sé qué pasa. No me deja imprimir porque dice

> 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Me dice que Sede es null, pero no entiendo.

¿Podrían explicarme por qué se produce este error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
public class RegistroSedes
    {

      public Sede[] sedes = new Sede[20];
        

        int contador = 0;


        public void Leersedes()
        {

                for (int i = 0; i <sedes.Length; i++)
                {

                    Sede objetoSede = new Sede();
                    ClasePrincipal principal = new ClasePrincipal();    

                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los datos de la sede "+(i+1));

                    Console.WriteLine("Proceso de Registro de Sedes.\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id de Sede :");
                    objetoSede.Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la sede :");
                    objetoSede.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Direccion :");
                    objetoSede.Direccion = Console.ReadLine();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Estado de la sede :");
                    //objetoSede.Estado = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su Telefono :");
                    objetoSede.Telefono = Console.ReadLine();

                    sedes[i] = objetoSede;



                    Console.WriteLine("Desea llenar un registro mas? NO/SI");
                    var respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "NO")
                    {
                    principal.MenuPrincipal();
                    break;

                    }

                    if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "SI")
                    {
                    continue;
                    }

                    contador++;

            }

           


        }

        public void listaSedes()
        {
           

            for (int i = 0; i <sedes.Length; i++)
            {
               

                Console.WriteLine(sedes[i].Id + "\t" + sedes[i].Nombre + "\t" + sedes[i].Direccion + "\t" + sedes[i].Telefono);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Este es un error frecuente, causado por el uso de una variable sin referencia (igual a `null`). Sería bueno que busquen otras preguntas sobre el mismo error e intenten resolverlo por su cuenta. Si no lo logran, ahí si hacen la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Espero lo siguiente te pueda ayudar, leer los comentarios del código**

1. **Al método `Leersedes()` agrégale que retorne un arreglo de sedes, de esta manera:**

```
public Sede[] Leersedes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sedes.Length; i++)
    {
        Sede objetoSede = new Sede();

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los datos de la sede " + (i + 1));

        Console.WriteLine("Proceso de Registro de Sedes.\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Id de Sede :");
        objetoSede.Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la sede :");
        objetoSede.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Direccion :");
        objetoSede.Direccion = Console.ReadLine();
        //Console.WriteLine("Estado de la sede :");
        //objetoSede.Estado = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su Telefono :");
        objetoSede.Telefono = Console.ReadLine();

        sedes[i] = objetoSede;

        Console.WriteLine("Desea llenar un registro mas? NO/SI");
        var respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadKey();

        if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "NO")
            break;

        if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "SI")
            continue;

        contador++;
    }
    return sedes;
}
```

2. **Al método `listaSedes()` agrégale para que reciba parámetros:**

```
public void listaSedes(Sede[] sedes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sedes.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(sedes[i].Id + "\t" + sedes[i].Nombre + "\t" + sedes[i].Direccion + "\t" + sedes[i].Telefono);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Ahora desde donde llamas a estos métodos haces lo siguiente:**

```
///Declara los objetos necesarios
RegistroSedes registroSedes = new RegistroSedes();
ClasePrincipal principal = new ClasePrincipal();

///Llamas a leer sedes donde se ingresan las sedes
///Te devolvera las sedes en un arreglo
var DatosSedes = registroSedes.Leersedes();

///Ahora si despues de eso tienes deseas ir al menu principal
///Entonces asegurate de que el método lista sedes este dentro de la ClasePrincipal
///Para que envíes la información de las sedes
principal.MenuPrincipal();

///Y cuando quieras presentar las sedes pues mandas por párametros las sedes
registroSedes.listaSedes(DatosSedes);
```

Comment: a ok entiendo gracias y una ultima cosa no es necesario instanciar la clase con el objeto asi sedes[i] = new Sede(); en el metodo ListaSedes() ?, porque travesiando lo puse y ahora si me dejo de tirar el error pero todo me sale en 0 me imagino que por lo que me comentaste que lo voy a probar muchas gracias

Comment: Es que al decirle sedes[i] = new Sede(); le dices que cree un objeto de sede vacío.
Y como el objeto sede es vacío por eso te sale 0.

Comment: aaaaah ya ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que sea por el cambio de contexto. ¿Qué quiero decir?
que si estás llamando a Leersedes() desde un punto diferente del programa y luego llamas a listaSedes() en el cambio de contexto se pierdan los datos. Lo que haría sería rellenar los datos y devolver un listado de sedes en el mismo contexto. Por ejemplo algo como: public sedes[] Leersedes(), una vez relleno el array sedes[] lo paso como parámetro de entrada al otro método tal que: listaSedes(sedes[]) .... por lo que al mostrarlo por pantalla mostrará los datos en el contexto indicado y no se pierde información. Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo

Comment: creo que no te entendi

Comment: Vale,  perdona, es que no puse el código, pero es justo lo que te puso el otro comentario. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracacias igualmente por querer tomarte el tiempo de responderme jajajj